# If the cord has a breaking strength of 25.0 N, explain why the cord broke when supporting a load so much lesser than its breaking strength

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

A picture of weight 5.0 N is suspended from a hook on the wall by a cord. The tension of the cord is 7.07 N. It was found that the picture is hung too low on the wall and was adjusted by shortening the cord. The new tension of the cord is 57.4 N. However, when the picture was adjusted, the cord breaks immediately. If the cord has a breaking strength of 25.0 N, explain why the cord broke when supporting a load so much lesser than its breaking strength.

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you were to consider the forces act on one of the points where the string connects to the painting.

Three forces act:
The force due to half the load's weight, 2.5N vertically downwards.

The tension of the string, direction is at a shallow angle above the horizontal.

A sideways reaction force acting horizontally in a manner opposing the horizontal component of the tension force.

Now, in order for equilibrium to be satisfied, one of the criteria is that the net vertical force equals zero.

This means the vertical component of the tension must equal the force due to half the load's weight.

However, as the tension is at a shallow angle above the horizontal, its vertical component is a small proportion of the full tension force.

Therefore, to ensure the vertical component equals the load's half weight, the tension must be large enough, likely a number of times larger than the weight of the load.

To ensure the string doesn't snap, it is better to have the string make a less shallow angle to the horizontal.